# How to generate PEM files to install my own SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, pem, chain, bitrix

I have a SSL-certificate Comodo PositiveSSL.

There are files:

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
domain.com.key
domain_com.crt
```

Requirements vendor:

```
The certificate, private key, and certificate chain must be PEM-encoded
/ssl/test1.bx.key.pem
/ssl/test1.bx.cert.pem
/ssl/test1.bx.ca-chain.cert.pyem
```

Do I create PEM files correctly?

```
cat COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > domain.com.ca-chain.cert.pem
cat domain_com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > domain.com.cert.pem
cat domain.com.key domain_com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > domain.com.key.pem
```

Comment: Learn a tool such as openssl.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I create PEM files correctly?

No. The key file should not be the result of concatenated files. I don't know your vendor, but I believe `domain.com.key` = `/ssl/test1.bx.key.pem`

What I suppose to be expected from your vendor, but I can't be sure of course

```
/ssl/test1.bx.cert.pem = domain_com.crt

/ssl/test1.bx.ca-chain.cert.pyem = AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt + COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt + COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

To setup certificates in bitrix env you need to do next:

1. Concatenate the CAbundle and the certificate file which we sent you using next:

1.1. To concatenate the certificate files into single bundle file, first open domainname.crt and domainname.ca-bundle files using any text editor.

1.2 Now copy all the content of domainname.crt and paste it on the top of domainname.ca-bundle file.

1.3 Now save the file name as ‘ssl-bundle.crt’.

2. Store the bundle and private key in the appropriate nginx ssl folder `/etc/nginx/ssl/example_com/`
3. Add this lines to your nginx config:

   ```
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/domainname.key;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ```
4. Restart nginx running command `systemctl restart nginx.service`.

Take a look into Comodo Knowledgebase about [certificate installation](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1091/37/certificate-installation--nginx) on nginx. They described step-by-step how to install certificates on different web-servers.